# Protractor: Logging Actions

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have been given a requirement to log all actions that protractor. Something along the lines of

```
console.log(action + " was called with arguments " + args.join(", ");
```

My first effort was to wrap the globally available browser.driver in a Proxy object then use this proxied object in my tests, and log the action before passing the call on to the target. This works for methods such as "get" however this does not seem to capture events such as click, and sendKeys. I tried wrapping the globally available element function in a Proxy as well however this didn't work and only seemed to randomly output the "all" method being called.

Is there an easy way to log the webdriver actions which are called?

Comment: If report can help you out then try using extent report for this. I have seen pretty report using extent for protractor.

Comment: I'm not sure how using a Jasmine report would help here? It's about logging calls on the underlying webdriver

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested to create custom reporter. You can create a wrapper function for every event.

> Please refer below example for click():

```
module.exports = {
    Click: function (elem, logName) {
        elem.click().then(function () {
            customReporter.addResult('Performed click for  ' + logName);
        }, function (err) {
            customReporter.addResult('Failed to click on "' + logName + '" due to "' + err.message + '"');
            expect(false).toBe(true);
        });
    },
};
```

logName - is a name passed which can be shown in report.

With this approach, you can record all your actions in some file.

Comment: My hope was to avoid code duplication where possible. Because using this method, I'll have to implement click, sendkeys etc etc just to have the same log line over and over

Comment: Yes, with this way you need to write wrapper for most of the functions. I will see if I find anything short for it to work.

Comment: I originally tried using an ES6 Proxy and trapping the get call but it only works for browser.driver.get(). It doesn't work when trying to wrap an element() call